# How would I display certain JSON data using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a Chrome extension which I am using to take JSON data from an external URL and then output the results in the console.

My external JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "reason": "test",
  "stats": {
    "number_of_items": "",
    "recently_updated": 0
  },
  "catalog_items": [
    [5207053, "White Witch Hat", "1,000", 1869],
    [31149956, "Hot Pink Faberg\u00e9 Egg", "800", 1409]
  ]
}
```

I would like to display all the objects which are in `"catalog_items"`. By using the code below, it outputs in the console:

```
$.getJSON('https://example.com', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

-

```
{success: true, reason: "test", stats: {…}, catalog_items: Array(15)}
catalog_items
:
(15) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
reason
:
"test"
stats
:
{number_of_items: "", recently_updated: 0}
success
:
true
__proto__
:
Object
```

However this is not what I want. I would like it to display:

```
ID: 5207053 Title: White Witch Hat Price: 1,000 RAP: 1869
ID: 31149956 Title: Hot Pink Faberg\u00e9 Egg Price: 800 RAP: 1409
```

Comment: you need to move it into a instance of class with a tostring method

Comment: Where's your output statements? You're not currently doing anything with the generated object - just `console.log()`'ing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `catalog_items` and concat the data to a string like this:

```
$.getJSON('https://example.com', function(data) {
    var catalog_items = data.catalog_items
    for(var i=0;i<catalog_items.length;i++){
        var item = catalog_items[i]
        var line = 'ID: '+item[0]
        line += ' Title: '+item[1]
        line += ' Price: '+item[2]
        line += ' RAP: '+item[3]
        console.log(line)
    }
});
```

To only show new entries you need to keep track of the IDs.

```
var shown_products = []

$.getJSON('https://example.com', function(data) {
    var catalog_items = data.catalog_items
    for(var i=0;i<catalog_items.length;i++){
        var item = catalog_items[i]

        if(shown_products.indexOf(item[0])!=-1) // product already shown
            continue

        var line = 'ID: '+item[0]
        line += ' Title: '+item[1]
        line += ' Price: '+item[2]
        line += ' RAP: '+item[2]
        console.log(line)
        shown_products.push(item[0])
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's just what I needed. Also, I am running the script every second using `setInterval(function() { }, 1000);`. How would I not repeat duplicate entries? So like only display what has changed since it last took the data. Please let me know if you don't know what I mean.

Comment: Hi thanks for that also.... I'm a bit of a noob to jQuery, but this is helping me to learn. I have another question about displaying `line` in a rich notification and I have a code but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Do you have an email or something so I could send it to you rather than having to make a new question please?

Comment: Hey, how would the script be any faster if I first checked if there was anything on `data.catalog_items` and if so, not do anything (like create the variable `line`)?

Answer (score 0):

Altho there is a lot of useful answers above, this one uses `console.table`

```js
// console.table polyfill
if (!console.table) {
  console.table = function(arr) {
    var keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);
    var horizontalLine = '\r\n' + '-'.repeat(8 * keys.length) + '\r\n';
    var heading = Object.keys(arr[0]).join('\t');

    var str = horizontalLine;
    str += heading;

    arr.forEach(function(obj) {
      str += horizontalLine + Object.values(obj).join('\t\t');
    });
    str += horizontalLine;
    console.log('%c' + str, 'font-family: monospace');
  };
}

// your response data
var data = {
  "success": true,
  "reason": "test",
  "stats": {
    "number_of_items": "",
    "recently_updated": 0
  },
  "catalog_items": [
    [5207053, "White Witch Hat", "1,000", 1869],
    [31149956, "Hot Pink Faberg\u00e9 Egg", "800", 1409]
  ]
}

// simple class 
function Item(values) {
  this.id = values[0];
  this.title = values[1];
  this.price = values[2];
  this.rap = values[3];
}

var items = data.catalog_items.map(function(next) {
  return new Item(next);
});

console.table(items);
```

So see demo press *Run code snippet* and open browser developer console

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of using a table. Nice idea!